How often should I run the message consumers?
Magento 2.4.6
I am running this every minute via cronjob:
php bin/magento cron:run; > /dev/null 2>&1
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update &
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor &
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor &

After a couple of minutes, my SQL server states "too many connections". Tried disabling the cron job, which fixes the problem. I am sure its because of the consumers ... is this not the way to run them?
Thanks!

You don't need to run message consumers manually.
CRON will take care automatically for message queue.
To setup CRON correctly, Just run below command

php bin/magento cron:install

You can remove all entries from crontab which added manually and just setup CRON by running command php bin/magento cron:install

Jaha! Thanks, I will try!
